# ADLS Gen2 file iteration is much slower than with regular blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have a process that iterates over all files in a container within a ADLS-Gen2-enabled storage account. Performance is significantly worse than equivalent iteration over objects in a regular blob container.

To test this I simulated the prod ADLS environment by uploading 100k small (10kb) files to a test blob container. I used a nested directory structure that was 6 levels deep, such that the 100k files were distributed among ~14k leaf directories.

With regular blob storage, using the Azure.Storage.Blobs library in C# .NET 8.0, I can consistently iterate over the 100k objects in ~35 seconds.

With the ADLS Gen2 filesystem, if I use the same Azure.Storage.Blobs library, it takes more than 6 or sometimes 7 minutes to iterate over 100k objects.

If I use the Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake libraries it is a bit faster, but still consistently 4-5 minutes to iterate over 100k objects.

**Why the huge discrepancy? Is there any way to improve ADLS Gen2 object iteration performance?**

Note: for blob iteration I am using `BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync()`; for ADLS iteration I am using `DataLakeFileSystemClient.GetPathsAsync(recursive: true)`